# How to read with lines having different number of elements

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a txt file that look like this:

a,b,c
a,b,c,d
a,b
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d

with each line having possibly different items.
I tried the:

```
df = pd.read_csv('text.txt', sep = ',', header = None)
```

but it gave me error as 'Error tokenizing data'
Does anyone know how to solve it? to separate a txt file with ',' regardless of number of elements at each line. much appreciated!

Comment: If one of the answers below fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide `names` for all of your columns:

```py
import pandas as pd

print(pd.read_csv('text.txt', header=None, names=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]))
```

Output:

```
   0  1    2    3    4
0  a  b    c  NaN  NaN
1  a  b    c    d  NaN
2  a  b  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  a  b    c    d    e
4  a  b    c    d  NaN
```

---

Generated values are fine too:

```py
print(pd.read_csv('text.txt', header=None, names=range(0, 5)))
```

---

text.txt

```
a,b,c
a,b,c,d
a,b
a,b,c,d,e
a,b,c,d
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass in the `names` parameter:

```py
pd.read_csv(('text.txt', sep = ',', header = None, names=['a','b','c','d','e'])
```